# How does Struts 2 supports utf-8 encoding in multiple languages

Tags: java, utf-8, utf-16

I know that java uses `UTF-16` encoding. i.e. Java uses `16 bits` to encode a character. So java can support `65536` characters. So java can provide internationalization.

While I am working with Struts2 I have seen that Struts2 uses `UTF-8` encoding that means it can support only 256 characters like `ASCII` but still Struts2 supports Internationalization.

Now my question is how come a `UTF-8` encoding supports Internationalization only with 256 characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UTF-16 and UTF-8 are two of several encodings for the Unicode character set. There are up to 1114112 (0x0 to 0x10FFFF) codepoints in Unicode. UTF-16 encodes a Unicode codepoint in one or two 16-bit code units. UTF-8 encodes a Unicode codepoint in one to four 8-bit code units.

ASCII is a characters set with one encoding. It has 128 codepoints. By design of Unicode, the first 128 codepoints of Unicode are the same characters as ASCII.

Unicode is a bit more complicated than most character sets. In Unicode, a grapheme (a symbol that is presented in one location) is composed of one base codepoint and a sequence of any number of combining codepoints, such as umlaut or cedilla.

Java, JavaScript, .NET … use UTF-16 internally so that a string is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units, which means that there are uncounted number of codepoints and an uncounted number of graphemes. This makes iteration difficult and indexing impossible.

However, many standard functions like reading and writing to files use UTF-8 because it can save space for text in Western languages.

Answer (score 4):

UTF-8 uses up to 6 bytes (and restricted up to 4 bytes due [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629)) to encode characters in the form of 8-bit code units.
See [Wiki description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

Encoding is actually variable-length and called UTF-8 because it uses 8-bit code units. UTF-16 on other hand uses 16-bit code units (up to 2 16-bit code units, that makes 4 bytes maximum).

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to use UTF-8 in ASCII format (see  [RFC 5137](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5137)), i.e. `\uxxx`. If you are using ASCII character set you don't need to convert them to ISO-8859-1 encoding. For other character sets you need to use the [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html) tool to convert native encoding of `.properties` files to ISO-8859-1 encoding.